# Xamarin - Alarm triggers but Receiver doesn't get called

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

So I set up an Alarm using AlarmManager, adb logcat shows that the alarm triggers but it won't execute the Receiver's OnReceive function.

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.companyname.APPNAME.SEND.REPORT"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Alarm Creation:

```
        if (Exists(context)) return;
        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.companyname.APPNAME.SEND_REPORT");
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 1337, intent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.Instance;
        calendar.TimeInMillis = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();

        alarmMgr.SetInexactRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, calendar.TimeInMillis, 1000 * 10, alarmIntent);
```

Receiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Classes.Log.Write("Reports alarm received.");
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.Partial, "SendReports");
        wl.Acquire();

        Classes.Network.SendReportsAsync();

        wl.Release();
        Classes.Log.Write("Reports alarm finished.");
    }
}
```

ADB Logcat logs:

```
07-23 11:08:46.723  1312  1863 V AlarmManager: Triggering alarm #0: 0 when =1595491710351 package =com.companyname.APPNAME operation =*walarm*:com.companyname.APPNAME.SEND_REPORT flags =0x0
```

Receiver logs are never written to my log file and no reports are sent, meaning the Receiver was never executed.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
This is after I changed the Intent to typeof(AlarmReceiver), that's the output

```
07-23 17:43:20.616  1312  1863 V AlarmManager: Triggering alarm #0: 0 when =1595515400614 package =com.companyname.ReportOne operation =*walarm*:com.companyname.ReportOne/md5057b6bb0fb853ea7a7a76aecdac4ee0b.AlarmReceiver flags =0x0
```

AlarmReceiver still won't execute

UPDATE 2:

This is the current code for initiating the Alarm

```
public static void Init(Context context)
    {
        if (Exists(context)) return;
        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 1337, intent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

        // Set the alarm to start at 7:00 a.m.
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.Instance;
        calendar.TimeInMillis = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();

        Classes.Log.Write(string.Format("Initializing Alarm, next alarm will fire at {0}",
            DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(GetMilliseconds()).ToString("g")));

        alarmMgr.SetInexactRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, calendar.TimeInMillis, 1000 * 10, alarmIntent);
    }
```

Comment: Implicit broadcasts to (most) manifest-registered Receivers have been disallowed since Oreo. You need to use an explicit `Intent` instead; e.g., `new Intent(context, typeof(AlarmReceiver))` (I _think_ that syntax is right; I don't do Xamarin). You can then remove the `<intent-filter>` from the `<receiver>` element.

Comment: Should I still keep the receiver in the manifest then?
And by the way, should I leave it there for backwards comp?
@MikeM.

Comment: How exactly are you creating the `Intent` now? Also, yes, the `<receiver>` still needs to be in the manifest; it just doesn't need the `<intent-filter>`. There's no need to leave it for backward compatibility, because explicit `Intent`s have always worked, and is how it always should have been done, even though you'll see many, many examples out there that use implicit broadcasts, for some reason. Not sure why.

Comment: I've updated the question, that's the new Intent creation, and by the way - as stated in the question the alarm is fired, tho the Receiver is not executed
Maybe it's a game of namespaces and packages? @MikeM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some research I realized that in Xamarin you shouldn't be registering your receivers from the manifest file, Xamarin.Android provides an Attribute for that.

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = false)]
public class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Classes.Log.Write("Reports alarm received.");
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.Partial, "SendReports");
        wl.Acquire();

        //Classes.Network.SendReportsAsync();

        wl.Release();
        Classes.Log.Write("Reports alarm finished.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi  , glad have solved that ！Remember to mark the answer when you have time , that's will be helpful for other people occur the same porblem. :-)